# Why do I still need to unwrap Swift dictionary value?

Tags: swift, option-type

```
class X {
    static let global: [String:String] = [
        "x":"x data",
        "y":"y data",
        "z":"z data"
    ]

    func test(){
        let type = "x"
        var data:String = X.global[type]!
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error: `Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped`.

Why do I need to use `!` after `X.global[type]`? I'm not using any optional in my dictionary?

**Edited**:

Even if `X.global[type]` may not exist for the type, force unwrapping will still crash on runtime. A better approach may be:

```
if let valExist = X.global[type] {
}
```

but Xcode is giving me the wrong idea by hinting about optional type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dictionary accessor returns optional of its value type because it does not "know" run-time whether certain key is there in the dictionary or not.  If it's present, then the associated value is returned, but if it's not then you get `nil`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID116):

> You can also use subscript syntax to retrieve a value from the dictionary for a particular key. Because it is possible to request a key for which no value exists, a dictionary’s subscript returns an optional value of the dictionary’s value type. If the dictionary contains a value for the requested key, the subscript returns an optional value containing the existing value for that key. Otherwise, the subscript returns nil...

In order to handle the situation properly you need to unwrap the returned optional.

There are several ways:

**Option 1:**

```
func test(){
    let type = "x"
    if var data = X.global[type] {
        // Do something with data
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
func test(){
    let type = "x"
    guard var data = X.global[type] else { 
        // Handle missing value for "type", then either "return" or "break"
    }

    // Do something with data
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
func test(){
    let type = "x"
    var data = X.global[type] ?? "Default value for missing keys"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just realize that but force upwrapping will still crash at run-time so the better approach may be to do optional binding

Comment: @Ken, see edits to my answer.  Force-unwrapping (`!` after `X.global[type]`) is the last resort for unwrapping the returned optional, and is not something appropriate for your case, as far as I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the `Dictionary` implementation, `subscript` is returning a `ValueType` as optional because it doesn't know if the `key` is exists or not:

```
//Reading a key that is not present in `self` yields `nil`.
//Writing `nil` as the value for a given key erases that key from `self`.
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

So when we try to get a value from our `Dictionary` we get it as an optional from the `subscript`; that is we have to unwrap the optional to get the underlying object. As mentioned in earlier answers, option2 is preferred.

```
guard var data = X.global[type] else { 
    //key = 'type' doesn't exists
}
//key exists so do something with 'data'
```